# static property in c# 6

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I'm writing a small code to more understand about `property` and `static property`. Like these:

```
class UserIdentity
{
    public static IDictionary<string, DateTime> OnlineUsers { get; set; }
    public UserIdentity()
    {
        OnlineUsers = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
    }
}
```

or

```
class UserIdentity
{
    public IDictionary<string, DateTime> OnlineUsers { get; }
    public UserIdentity()
    {
        OnlineUsers = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
    }
}
```

Since I changed it to:

```
class UserIdentity
{
    public static IDictionary<string, DateTime> OnlineUsers { get; }
    public UserIdentity()
    {
        OnlineUsers = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
    }
}
```

it gave me error message:

> Property or indexer 'UserIdentity.OnlineUsers' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

I knew the property `OnlineUsers` was `read only`, but in C# 6, I can assign it via constructor. So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're trying to assign to a read only static property in an instance constructor. That would cause it to be assigned every time a new instance is created, which would mean it's not read only. You need to assign to it in the static constructor:

```
public static IDictionary<string, DateTime> OnlineUsers { get; }

static UserIdentity()
{
    OnlineUsers = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
}
```

Or you can just do it inline:

```
public static IDictionary<string, DateTime> OnlineUsers { get; } = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
```

Comment: The problem would also happen in C#1.0 onwards (generics aside), just with different syntax for declaring the OnlineUsers

Comment: @MartinCapodici: Then it'd have to be a field and not a property, because you couldn't have a "read only property that you can also assign to", which were added in C# 6.

Comment: Matti, that is true I was thinking of a field wrapped with a property to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, your constructors are missing the parenthesis `()`. A correct constructor looks like this:

```
public class UserIdentity {

     public UserIdentity() {
        ...
     }
}
```

For your question: 
Readonly properties can only be assigned in the constructor of the specific context. A `static` property is not bound to a specific instance but to the class.

In your second code snippet `OnlineUsers` is non static, thus it can be assigned to in the constructor of a new instance, and only there.

In your third snippet, `OnlineUsers` is static. Thus, it can only be assigned to in a static initializer.

```
class UserIdentity
{
    public static IDictionary<string, DateTime> OnlineUsers { get; }

    //This is a static initializer, which is called when the first reference to this class is made and can be used to initialize the statics of the class
    static UserIdentity()
    {
        OnlineUsers = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Static readonly property must be assigned in static constructor like this:

```
public static class UserIdentity
{
    public static IDictionary<string, DateTime> OnlineUsers { get; }

    static UserIdentity()
    {
        OnlineUsers = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
    }
}
```